# Does the java optimizer eliminate code whose result is not used unless an exception is thrown

Tags: java, compiler-optimization, jit

Consider following code (java 8):

```
try
{
    // try to create an instance of CardExpirationDate
    AfCardExpirationDate.getInstance( anExpMonth, anExpYear);
    return true;    // expiration date is valid
}
catch ( IllegalArgumentException e )    
{
    // invalid expiration date
    return false;
}
```

The result of the call to `AfCardExpirationDate.getInstance`is never used. We check here only if it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` or not.

Is this safe? Or could a compiletime or runtime code optimizer strip off such a call?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to just create a logic like `AfCardExpirationDate.isValid(anExpMonth, anExpYear)` over actually giving meaning to an exception? Feels like a missuse of the Exception to me.

Comment: It would have to be a pretty careless optimizer that assumes `getInstance()` won't have any side effects.

Comment: The method can be inlined and any results not used can be discarded. However, a check which triggers an exception can't be discarded (unless the check is of a `static final boolean` e.g. assertions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can't optimize this out. Plain and simple.

The compiler can't know if that unsuspicious call to `getInstance()` doesn't have side effects. Beyond that, the compiler **obviously** does notice that your method has two return paths, and that therefore the try/catch matters.

Beyond that, as a Java programmer you do **not** care about optimisation steps that happen between java source code and class file byte code.

The JIT at runtime has profiling information, and when it finds that method is invoked so often that it is worth optimizing, it will compile it at runtime to machine code. Doing all the things that a compiler with contextual profile knowledge can possibly do.

Finally: you are mis-using try/catch for **validation** purposes. That is simply bad practice (for example because of the associated runtime performance cost). When you are really serious about A) code quality and B) runtime performance then simply allow the complete validation to take place without relying on some code throwing up.

Comment: Yes you are right that this code mis-uses the try/catch. But currently I have no other choice unless re-implementing the validation logic which is already present within the AfCardExpirationDate (private). But thank you for your useful explanations. This code runs in an ATM where runtime performance is not of the highest priority.

Comment: Interesting setup. But I assume this is still some J2SE jre, that has some JIT compiler? Or small, embedded?

Comment: It's the normal JRE 8 distribution